redshift select distinct rows (group by columns) that contain NULL
what is the best way to get distinct records from the table containing 500 mln records? table structure is id1, id2, id3, upload_date. sample data
id1    id2    id3    upload_date
1       ab    cd     20240525
2       null  gh     20240331
2       null  gh     20240228

needed result
id1    id2    id3    upload_date
1      ab     cd     20240525
2      null   gh     20240331

there can be null in all columns except id1 that is the key and upload_date. if i use groupping by max(upload_date) because of NULLs i get duplications. if i use nvl for null columns, than as a result i miss nulls, when i use select distinct id1, id2, id3, i don't get max(upload_date) that is required. maybe row_numner(over partition by id1 order by upload_date desc) as row_id and get from there everything with row_id = 1? but will it wotk fine for 500 mln records?

If I understand your requirement correctly, a simple aggregation query should suffice here:
SELECT id1, id2, id3, MAX(upload_date) AS upload_date
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY id1, id2, id3;

Given that you are running Redshift, you could also use DISTINCT ON here:
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id1, id2, id3) id1, id2, id3, upload_date
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY id1, id2, id3, upload_date DESC;


hmmm. strange, now grouping works. the reason i posted was that it returned me duplicates. thanks a lot, i'll try the second option too, it's interesting, have never used
